How to handle this scenario in an ASP .NET Web API?
I have an endpoint that creates a new category, the category entity has a property called CategoryCode, which is unique and is calculated based on the last value in the database.
For simplicity, let's just assume that I get the max CategoryCode value and increment it.
[HttpPost]
[Route("TestAwait")]
public async Task<ActionResult<GeneralApiResponse<StoreHistoryResponse>>> TestAwait(TestModel testId)
{
    try
    {
        var categoryCode = await _context.Categories.MaxAsync(x => x.CategoryCode);
        Debug.WriteLine($"Category Max Code {categoryCode} From {testId.StoreId}");
        var newCategoryCode = ++categoryCode;

        await Task.Delay(20000); //For Testing

        var newCategory = new Category()
        {
            CategoryName = $"Test {newCategoryCode}",
            CategoryCode = newCategoryCode,
            BranchId = 1
        };

        await _context.Categories.AddAsync(newCategory);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(newCategory);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : ex.Message);
    }
}

Now the problem that faces me is when multiple clients call this endpoint at the same time, some of them won't have the latest max value.
So my question here is how can I handle this scenario so that when multiple clients call the end point at the same time, they will all have the latest values in the database?
I'm not sure if this has nothing to do with dependency injection or
if I can make this endpoint await all clients, not just a specific client or there some other solution?

use a database-sequence if you want auto-incrementing. Otherwise you need to rollout your own lock. How you achieve that depends on how many processes/threads you have.

This is a classical example of a race condition, somewhere you need a lock so that only one thread at a time can read -> increment -> write the value at any given time. Either implement it in your C# code or preferably have the database generate it for you.

See also this discussion

if all simultaneous clients will have same key - there would be a collapse on insert multiple records with same id.

there are 2 most popular approaches

make column autoincremented -so you don't worry about simultaneous calls.
have a table to maintain next id, and all processes will call that stored proc or function to get new id:

call stored proc to get and store max id to that table and return that id back, so in multiple calls you will always get a new unique id without overlapping.
as example:
--creating environment
create table MAINTABLE (ID int, name varchar(20))
insert into MAINTABLE values (1,'existing record 1'),(2,'existing record 2')

CREATE table IDMaintain (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null, TableName varchar(20), NextID int)
insert IDMaintain Values ('MAINTABLE', 2)

select * from Maintable
select * from IDMaintain

--inside stored proc to get next id:
declare @nextID int

UPDATE IDMaintain SET 
  NextID = NextID + 1
WHERE TableName = 'MAINTABLE'

select @NextID = NextID from IDMaintain WITH (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)
--return that id
select NextID = @nextID

--add new record
insert into MAINTABLE (ID, Name) VALUES (@nextID, 'New Record 1')
select * from MAINTABLE


working example here
P.S. disadvantages: if record was not created for some reason - you loose that id, so it would be gaps in sequence.
don't forget to wrap in transaction and use WITH (UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK)
